# electron Render process gone: { reason: 'crashed', exitCode: 133 }

Tags: javascript

electron version: v15.4.1
operating system: Kylin Linux
arch: arm

The software created using Electron crashed after running on a Linux system for 5 days, with error message: { reason: 'crashed', exitCode: 133 }

Rxjs was used in the project, and it has caused crashes before. This time, I made some changes to its listening events, but the problem still exists